# Store email that are used to log in and show as suggestion on the email input during next Login - Android Application

Tags: android, arraylist, authentication, sharedpreferences

I am trying to find a way to keep all the email used for login into the application in a device and show them as suggestion or autocomplete when ever a user tries to login in to the application.

I tried using shared preferences and store them into an ArrayList during the login. However each time I login, the email gets replaced with the latest login email instead of adding up.

Example: first i login with admin@admin.com and logout from the system. For next login the suggestion admin@admin.com shows up. However if now i login with employee@employee.com, the old stored email is replaced with the new one.

What I did to get this was first after login I stored the user email from the server response in a shared preference.

Next I put that data into an ArrayList

```
    SharedPreferences getEmail = getSharedPreferences("userEmail", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String input_email = getEmail.getString("emp_email", "");

    ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(input_email);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userList);
    if (userList.size() > 0){
        userEmail.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The above code in inside the onCreate method of the login activity. How can i do this.
I am guessing maybe this is not the correct way to remember email address for auto suggestion. If so then please point me to the right direction.

Thank you.

Update

Fetching response from the server in LoginActivity on successful login

```
public void getDataForId() {

    SharedPreferences authToken = getSharedPreferences("authToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String token = authToken.getString("token", "");

    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<UserResponse> call = apiInterface.getData("Bearer " + token);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                String emp_email = response.body().getUser().getEmail();

                ArrayList<String> listEmails = getFromPrefs(this);

                if(listEmails == null){
                   listEmails = new ArrayList<>();
                   listEmails.add(emp_email);
                }

                saveToPrefs(this, listEmails);

                /*Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + getFromPrefs(this).toString());

                if(!listEmails.contains(emp_email)){
                   listEmails.add("b@b.b");
                }

                saveToPrefs(this, listEmails);

                Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + getFromPrefs(this).toString());*/


            } else {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

Note that in am getting the email in the variable **emp_email* (assume the other two functions given by you are in the file). What I assume is that the commented out part (after the first email is saved), will start in the onCreate methode for me as after logging out.

there i get the pref data see it the new email matched the pref data and then store it. This is when it is getting replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
I have edited your code

gist.github.com/adrielAd/b1fbc4f8665183eb195871d21cd415eb

```
// make listEmails global and also initialise this in onCreate so you get already saved emails when you come to this screen
ArrayList<String> listEmails;

public void getDataForId() {

    SharedPreferences authToken = getSharedPreferences("authToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String token = authToken.getString("token", "");

    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<UserResponse> call = apiInterface.getData("Bearer " + token);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                String emp_email = response.body().getUser().getEmail();

                listEmails = getFromPrefs(this);

                if(listEmails == null){
                   listEmails = new ArrayList<>();
                   listEmails.add(emp_email);
                }else{
                  if(!listEmails.contains(emp_email)){
                     listEmails.add(emp_email);
                  }
                }


                saveToPrefs(this, listEmails);

                /*Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + getFromPrefs(this).toString());

                if(!listEmails.contains(emp_email)){
                   listEmails.add("b@b.b");
                }

                saveToPrefs(this, listEmails);

                Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + getFromPrefs(this).toString());*/


            } else {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> listEmails = getFromPrefs(this);

    if(listEmails == null){
        listEmails = new ArrayList<>();
        listEmails.add("a@a.a");
    }

    saveToPrefs(this, listEmails);

    Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + getFromPrefs(this).toString());

    if(!listEmails.contains("b@b.b")){
        listEmails.add("b@b.b");
    }

    saveToPrefs(this, listEmails);

    Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + getFromPrefs(this).toString());

}

public static void saveToPrefs(Context context, ArrayList<String> listEmail) {
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String list = gson.toJson(listEmail);
    prefsEditor.putString("list", list);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}


public static ArrayList<String> getFromPrefs(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String list = appSharedPrefs.getString("list", "");
    ArrayList<String> listEmail = gson.fromJson(list, ArrayList.class);
    return listEmail;
}
```

Here is the screenshot for logs [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise. I have been busy all day with work so i could not check it. I will do asap and give a feedback for others to see.

Comment: what is did was

 `ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<>();`
at the start of the class. Then I added the server response of the email to the userList like
`String emp_email = response.body().getUser().getEmail();

                    if (!userList.contains(emp_email)){
                        userList.add(emp_email);
                    }`

then saved it to tinyBD like 
`TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(LoginActivity.this);
                    tinydb.putListString("user_email_id", userList);`
Now, when i get this string, i still only get the last logged in user id like before.

Comment: Did you reinitialised the list with tinyDB list? And then added the new email id in that list?

Comment: Yes.
However I maybe found the reason, somewhere I read that an ArrayList gets destroyed as garbage collector once an app is closed. Hence I'm getting an empty list everytime.

Comment: But if you initialise arraylist with the list stored then it should give you all email ids that you ave stored

Comment: when im initializing the arrayList with list stored, i got something like `[adminone@admin.com, adminone@admin.com]`. Maybe my initialization was wrong. However, what i did was save the data to a text file and read it back when i needed it.

Comment: just edited my answer. Please check that out. For gson you can add

implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2"

in gradle

Comment: In your solution you have taken two static strings to append the user list. For my case, i have one string variable which stores an email address sent from the server as response. What I think is happening in my case is, when I am getting a response, my string variable is changing and hence when I'm trying to append the array list, its simply getting replaced.

Comment: In your case if you enter one email at one time and save that by appending the list then every time you come to login screen and fetch the stored list you will be getting 1 email that you stored? right? Now when after logout you enter new email you can append that too in existing list and store that list in shared pref. In this way you can relate this to my 2 static strings.

Comment: I very much appreciate the time and effort you are investing into this. I cannot thank you enough. I have updated my question with what i did. Please if you dont mind, can you look into that.

Comment: try adding this in your code

if(listEmails == null){
            listEmails = new ArrayList<>();
            listEmails.add(emp_email);
        }else{
            if(!listEmails.contains(emp_email)){
                listEmails.add(emp_email);
            }
        }

Comment: try this. I have edited your code

https://gist.github.com/adrielAd/b1fbc4f8665183eb195871d21cd415eb

Comment: I dont know how can I thank you. It worked. I really cannot thank you enough for helping me with this. Can you please update your answer with this code so i can mark it correct. Thank you a thousand times.

Comment: I have added a new answer, as old answer shows about saving list in shared preferences